# How to change inner page content ineffective of page refresh?

Tags: ajax

I tried to change inner content of my web page by using ajax but it revert back when I refresh the page, how can I prevent that? I am working on PHP and JS.

Comment: you need a stateful server to achieve this, where server keep track of every action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of all modifications made via ajax and apply them on the server when the page is generated next time.